# bigint Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, bigint

Description of problem:
I'm attempting to create a big integer class using operator overloading, and I believe so far so good, but I keep getting this error when I attempt to compile. Any idea what the problem could be? It doesn't give me an error for the input, only the output.

**Error: undefined reference to `bigint::tostring() const'**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED


using namespace std;

class bigint{

public:
    bigint(); //default constructor - set this to zero
    bigint(int x0);
    bigint(int x0, int x1);
    bigint(int x0, int x1, int x2);
    bigint(int x0, int x1, int x2, int x3);
    bigint(int x0, int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4);
    string tostring() const;


private:
    int v[5];
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream & out, const bigint outpt){
out << outpt.tostring();
return out;
}


istream& operator >>(istream & in, const bigint& inpt){
return in;
} //need to fix this


bigint & operator +(const bigint & ls, const bigint & rs) {
return bigint(ls) + rs;
}//addition operator

bigint & operator -(const bigint & ls, const bigint & rs){
    return bigint(ls) - rs;
} //subtraction operator

bool operator <(const bigint & ls, const bigint rs){
    return bigint(ls) < rs;
} //use bool because these values can only be true or false

bool operator >(const bigint & ls, const bigint rs){
    return bigint(ls) > rs;
}

bool operator >=(const bigint & ls, const bigint rs){
    return bigint(ls) >= rs;
}

bool operator <=(const bigint & ls, const bigint rs){
    return bigint(ls) <= rs;
}

bool operator ==(const bigint & ls, const bigint rs){
    return bigint(ls) == rs;
}

bool operator !=(const bigint & ls, const bigint rs){
    return bigint(ls) != rs;
}


#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Where is Your implementation of tostring?

Comment: i don't see a implemetation of tostring().

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a minimal working example in which the problem appears, strip out everything that you don't need (e.g. constructors not used, operators not used, etc...).

Comment: Undefined reference is a linker error. It's not a compile error. You did not define the thing in the error message, you forgot to link the file that defines it, you forgot to link to the library that defines it, or, if it's a static library, you have the wrong order on the linker command line. Check which one. (Note that some linkers call it an unresolved external)

Comment: half your rhs args miss &

Comment: Your `operator<<` should take a const reference (insted of a value which has to be copied) and your `operator>>` should take a non-const reference (for modifying) and of coures what BalogPal wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see your implementation of `tostring()` coded. You must code your own implementation of `tostring()`.

The function will get the number, convert it to a string and return the string. You can use `stream`, `itoa` or `sprintf`.

If there is any native `tostring()` method elsewhere, check that the S of "string" surely will be uppercase instead of lowercase (`toString()`).